# How To Host My Telegram Bot [JAVA] Using Heroku & Maven and GitHub?

Tags: java, maven, heroku, telegram-bot, host

My pom.xml File :

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TelegramBOT</groupId>
  <artifactId>TelegramBOT</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>13</release>
          <appName>TelegramBOT</appName>
          <processTypes>
          <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
          </processTypes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.telegram/telegrambots -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>4.9</version>
</dependency>
   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is The Build Of pom.xml But I am Not Able To Host In Heroku... Its Shows An Error

```
       [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  10.182 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-28T11:59:51Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TelegramBOT: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_07ca4d72478d669dcc1d1150921b9882/src/com/TelegramBot/EraserHead/GameHandler.java:[17,60] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
       [ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
       [ERROR] /tmp/build_07ca4d72478d669dcc1d1150921b9882/src/com/TelegramBot/EraserHead/ImageGuess.java:[23,60] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
       [ERROR]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
       [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

This The Heroku Console ....

But In Eclipse Console Its Says BUILD SUCCESSFUL!
I Can't Figure Out What To Do ... Do I Really Need To Create Procfile ???
Please Help... If You Need to See The Source Code Of My Program,
It Is There In My GitHub Account : https://github.com/saikat0326/Saikat-Telegram-BOT
Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the Maven Compiler plugin is using Java 5 (it should be using Java 6 by default), hence you get the build error `diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5`

Heroku supports various Java version (see [Supported Java versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions)), you should just be able to set the target version in your POM file

```
<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The diamond operator – introduced in Java 1.7 – adds type inference and reduces the verbosity in the assignments.

Problem in your source code try to re-write it.

I had similar issu and my now looks like this

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>4.1.3</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.12.1</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>3.3.1-1</webjars-jquery.version>
    <java.version>${java.version}</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${versions-maven-plugin.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```